# Which has the responsibility to sort the items in MVVM pattern and a DataGrid?

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm, datagrid, short

I have a dataGrid in a wpf application that use the MVVM pattern.

The dataGrid can sort the row if I click in the column name and I can order by many columns if I use the shift key. So the control gives all I need.

However, I notice that when I have sorted the rows and I add a new element, the new element is really add as last element in my observable collection in my view model, but in the dataGrid is show in the position that this element has according to the sort criterion.

So in my view model I try to select the new element. I get the index of the last element of my observalbeCollection, but then this select the incorrect element in the DataGrid, the last element shown, but this is not my new element.

[In this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743904/how-to-get-the-correct-index-in-a-datgrid-when-i-use-the-mvvm-pattern-and-i-have) it seems that one solution is to use a CollectionViewSource, but if I am not wrong, in this case I need to implement in my view model all the code to sort elements, so is more code when the dataGrid does this work.

This makes me ask which has really the responsibility to sort the elements? the view model or the view? Because if I implent the sort in my view model, the view model needs to know that exists a datagrid that is clicked in some column name and the sort the elements. I think that sort the elements is something visual, so the view model does not need to do that work, but perhaps I am wrong.

How could I solve  this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I put data into any collection control in WPF (using MVVM), I always bind to the collection `ItemsSource` property *as well as* the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedItems` properties, depending on the `SelectionMode` of the control.

This enables me to find out which item(s) is/are selected *and* to choose whichever (data) item I want to be selected from the view model.

If the order that the user sets in the `DataGrid` is important, then I would perform the sorting from the view model, but if it is only important to the user while they work, then you can simply ignore the order... remember, you can access the selected item through the bound `SelectedItem` property in your view model.

Comment: Yes I use to work like you, with SelectedItems, but in this case I want to select the item in the view model and then in the dataGrid, to scroll the selected item. If I have many rows in the dataGrid, I don't want the user scroll to the selected item, I would like that this is automatic.

Comment: I can scroll automatically, but then the selected item in the datagrid is not sync with the selected item in my view model.

Comment: This is the right way to go... You can automatically scroll to the selected item using `Attached Properties` without losing the selected item. There are plenty of examples of this online if you search.

Comment: Well, in my case I use a behavior, perhaps is the same. But in the special case that I add a new element in my collection of the view model when I have a sort in the dataGRid, the selected item in the dataGrid is not sync with the element position in my property of the view model.

Comment: If you want the items in the same order as they appear in the `DataGrid`, try iterating through the read only `DataGrid.Items` property. I haven't tried binding to it, but it is a bindable property too, with `Mode=OneWay` of course.